# Key-value хранилище для Android

Tags: android, nosql, key-value

Существуют ли для Android NoSQL-хранилища аналогичные Redis или Memcache?

Стандартный SharedPreferenses не подходит, т.к. может хранить только простые типы данных. А, мне нужно сохранить объект или массив объектов.

Comment: существуют базы данных

Comment: если не хочется поднимать БД, можно придумать костыли... Конвертить объекты или списки с объектами в JSON и сохранять в SharedPreferenses - но так делать не хорошо.. Это дикое костылирование.

Comment: Может быть подскажете key-value БД под Android?

Comment: На Андроиде нет таких БД. Андроид использует SQLite. Другое дело что в БД можно сохранять как в обычные реляционные БД при запуске делать выборку и кешировать например в Map где будет key-value. Есть ORM над базой данный называется Room - почитайте. Туда можно записывать те же списки объектов - если описать как конвертировать (конвертить в JSON и обратно) - но это тоже костыли. Не такие как с SharedPreferenses, но тоже ерунда. Правильно использовать SQLite - делать выборку а дальше преобразуйте как вам удобно.

Comment: Посмотрите вот это: https://realm.io/products/realm-database

Comment: Realm отличный вариант и прост в использовании, плюс из коробки можно получить слушатели на обновление данных и работу в асинхронном режиме, достаточно гибкое составление выборки.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужно хранить большое количество объектов, тогда SharedPreferenses - самый лучший вариант. Как выше уже сказали, достаточно написать generic-метод для сериализации объектов в json-строку и десериализацию из json через Gson.

Самое главное, нужно помнить, что физически SharedPreferences - это обычный xml-файл (хоть и базовой системой кэширования). Да, получается, что вы храните json внутри xml. Но, повторюсь, это не является проблемой в случае хранения ограниченного количества объектов.

Если же объектов много и их нужно часто изменять - тогда только БД.

Comment: О сериализации в JSON и даже о хранении в `Set<String>` я знаю. Но, с этими способами связан целый ряд накладных расходов. Поэтому основная суть моего вопроса именно в том, как без SharedPreferenses обойтись.